# Values are setting on place in flot chart

Tags: javascript, flot

I am trying to plot a chart in my page.Am able to set the chart values properly.But the values are not setting. Because of this am getting space at the  end .

```
var DataSet1 = [ 
                 [new Date("2014/03/03").getTime(), 0],
                [new Date("2014/03/10").getTime(), 16 ],
                [new Date("2014/03/17").getTime(), 32 ],
                [new Date("2014/03/24").getTime(), 189],
                [new Date("2014/03/31").getTime(), 250]         ];

    var DataSet2 = [ 
                 [new Date("2014/03/03").getTime(), 0],
                [new Date("2014/03/10").getTime(), 40],
                [new Date("2014/03/17").getTime(), 20 ],
                [new Date("2014/03/24").getTime(), 180],
                [new Date("2014/03/31").getTime(), 230] ];


        /* to find last 4 weeks mondays */

            var newDate = new Date();
            var day = newDate.getDay();
            var date = newDate.getDate();
            var xaxisArray = [];
            for(var i = 0;i<5;i++){if(i!=0){
                    var tempnewDate = new Date(setNewDate);
                    setNewDate =tempnewDate.setDate(tempnewDate.getDate()-(7));
                    xaxisArray.push(setNewDate);
                } else {
                    setNewDate =newDate.setDate(date-day+1);
                    xaxisArray.push(setNewDate);
                }               
            }

            $.plot($("#chart-revenue2"),[
                { data: DataSet1,label: "#FST",},
                { data: DataSet2, label: "SCND", 
                   points: { show: true },
                   lines: { show: true,fill: false},
                   yaxis: 2,color:"#C76C6B"} ] ,
                {
                  xaxis: 
                        {
                            mode: "time", 
                            min: xaxisArray[4],
                            max:xaxisArray[0],
                            timeformat: "%d/%m/%y",
                            ticks: xaxisArray.reverse(),
                            minTickSize :30
                        }
                    , yaxes: [
                            {   
                                 min:0, max: 400,  tickSize: 50 
                            },
                            {                   
                                position: "right",
                                min:0, max: 300,  tickSize: 50                              
                            }
                        ], 
                         series: {                        
                            lines: { 
                                show: true,
                                lineWidth: 3, 
                                fill: true
                           },
                           shadowSize: 0,
                       },
                        grid: {backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#f4f4f4"] }},
                        colors: ["#294777"],
                        legend: { show: true, container: '#chart-revenue1-table' }

            });
```

Please check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htsBz/)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are calculating the dates for your axis ticks.  When you create `newDate`, it has hours, minutes and seconds, which are then included in each tick.  Make sure they are all zero and it will all line up:

```
var newDate = new Date()
newDate.setHours(0);
newDate.setMinutes(0);
newDate.setSeconds(0);
```

There's probably a better way to do that, I just haven't looked it up :)

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/htsBz/1/

Answer (score 1):

You've set the maximum on the xaxis beyond the last point you have data for. What did you expect it to do? It doesn't have data, so it leaves it blank. If you want your axis to fit, set it's max to `max: new Date("2014/03/31").getTime()`, or better yet, just don't set the max and let flot autoscale it for you.

Comment: Please check the axis points.The values are not sit properly.In red line values are not sit according to x axis.

Comment: Good try Matt - and I agree with the min/max being set uselessly... Based on @chan's comment, and the poorly worded question, I think the actual question is why the points don't line up with the xaxis ticks